# signed and unsigned integers as bits in memory

Tags: binary

I am looking into making a memory scanner for values an while doing some research I came across this the piece of information that unsigned integers allocate all 8 bits for the number while signed ones save the first bit for the sign

My question is, how can I distinguish between them in memory?

I can interpret the number both ways, but how could I tell if it was meant to be negative or positive?

Comment: you cant tell without context 0xdeadbeef can be 3735928559 or -559038737 or for that matter float or double  try .formats 0xdeadbeef in windbg or take a look at datainspector in hxd for various interpretations of a single DWORD

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a C level type and doesn't actually exist on a binary level. In a binary level, there are only bytes. What is interesting for you, is how those bytes are treated - if they are treated as unsigned int, signed int, char or any other data type.

For example, Let's look at the following ARM assembly sample:

```
ROM:40061B00                 CMP.W   R1, #0x60
ROM:40061B04                 BGT     loc_80061B22
```

The value in `R1` is compared to 0x60. `R1` is a register that holds 32-bit (4 bytes) value. The value doesn't have any information about its signedness. But what is important is the operation that done at `40061B04`.

From ARM [specification](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1359731162080.html):

> HS    Unsigned higher or same
>
> GT    Signed greater than

So we have a compare at `40061B00` and then a decision if to branch to a certain location.
In our case, the mnemonic is `BGT` - meaning that we will branch if the signed comparison is greater than - therefore our `R1` treated as signed int. If the instruction was `BHS` - the comparison would be unsigned, and the value in `R1` would have been treated as an unsigned int.

Comment: i do know i can tell contextually based on the assembly but I do not yet have the skills to write a decompiler and interpret all these instructions and such

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't. To interpret memory contents you need to see the structure layout. It could be a float, an integer, a structure, a char array  or even a meaningless value on the border of two structures.

Long answer - you don't always have to.

About signed values, fundamentally, the system represents negative integers by counting backward and wrapping around - I find this much easier than always having to think about the sign bit. A nice consequence of this model is that all positive values (in signed range) are represented the same way, regardless of signed/ unsigned choice.

This means that if you find a positive value less or equal than (MAX_VALUE / 2 - 1), you can output it without worrying about signed/unsigned values. If you find a number greater than that, it's either that unsigned value or a signed value of (x - MAX_VALUE). MAX_VALUE is the largest unigned integer for your type.